# KnockoutJS and value binding (2-way)

Tags: knockout.js

I have a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shelbyz/bytM7/) where I'm trying to better understand value binding.  I have an input control value bound to a **search** property on my viewModel as follows:

```
<input data-bind="value: search" />
```

I have the **search** property as defined as:

```
this.search = ko.observable("");
```

I also have subscribe implemented on the "search" property as follows:

```
this.search.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    alert("New value is " + newValue);
    alert("New value is" + this.search);
});
```

I can see **newValue** change as I type and then select another control, but the viewModel property **search** does is always **undefined**.  I was expecting with 2-way binding that as I type information **search** would have the type value so that I could use it say in a button that executes a webservice call using ajax, but **undefined** is the only value that I can get in the field without setting the default value of the **search**.

Is it expected that I change the value of **search** in the subscribe call?  I thought this would be done for me by having it 2-way bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, within the `subscribe` method, `this` does not reference the view model and so there is no `search` property available (hence `undefined`).  You can work around this by saving a reference to the view model under another variable name such as `_self` and access `search` using that reference.

Secondly, you need to call `search` as a function in order to get it's value - this is true of all observable values when working with Knockout.

```
var viewModel = function() {
    var _self = this;
    this.search = ko.observable("");

    this.search.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        alert("New value is " + newValue);
        alert("New value is " + _self.search());
    });
};
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bytM7/2/)

Comment: You'll have to forgive me, I just had it set in my mind that these objects of the viewModel could be accessed like variable in C#.  I did see code saying that not all browsers supported accessing variables and that I might have to call them as a function, but for some reason I immediately dismissed this fact.  Thanks for this.

Comment: No problem, but afaik this is nothing to do with browsers; it is to do with Knockout - if you access `_self.search` through any browser then the result should always be `function(...) { ... }` as it *is* a function